# CRM-like webapp for managing clients and the ads they have purchased

Tags: web-apps, crm

We sell advertisement (banner, memberships,..) to a few dozens of clients, most of them are recurring (they have to pay once a month or less often). As the number of clients is not so high, we don't want to use a payment service.

**We want an easy to use webapp that allows to save and edit our clients and manage the products they have bought, especially the recurring payment: We need an alert every time a membership or banner has to be billed again.**

We tested **Pipedrive** quite a lot: It is a good tool for CRM and I can recommend it for classical usage of a CRM Tool. We could use Pipedrive for our purpose, but we would have to save a new "Product" for every user (most users have custom packages), and manually save alerts. So each time a user gets a new bill, we have to save a new alert, and so on..

A few years ago we tested **Salesforce**, but I did not like it: Too oldschool regarding usability and design (at least it was then), too complex and expensive.

We *don't* need a webapp for *invoices*, we have one, but it just makes our invoices.

Maybe we could use a project management tool like **Basecamp**. That would be cool because we need a project management tool anyway for collaborative working on new projects. But I did not find one that we could use for our payment alerts..